# AWS notification is failed after sending email to the user

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am using AWS to send emails in my project.. I created subscription and done all the steps. Its sending emails to the user but the notification is not receiving.. it says notification failed. I don't know the reason.. but I am getting notifications if I use http url instead https url.

The php code I am using is added below -

```
<?php

require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use AwsSnsMessageValidatorMessage;
use AwsSnsMessageValidatorMessageValidator;
use GuzzleHttpClient;

// Make sure the request is POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    http_response_code(405);
    die;
}

try {
    // Create a message from the post data and validate its signature
    $message = Message::fromRawPostData();
    $validator = new MessageValidator();
    $validator->validate($message);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Pretend we're not here if the message is invalid
    http_response_code(404);
    die;
}

if ($message->get('Type') === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
    // Send a request to the SubscribeURL to complete subscription
    (new Client)->get($message->get('SubscribeURL'))->send();
} elseif ($message->get('Type') === 'Notification') {
    // Do something with the notification
    save_message_to_database($message);
}
```

I am following the AWS documentation. Do you know the reason.. is there any issue in this code?